# Bug with anchored FloatingActionButton in support library 24.2.1

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport, floating-action-button

I have been having this issue since 24.2.0, but now I'm using 24.2.1 and the bug is still here, it only works well <= 24.1.1.

I have an anchored FloatingActionButton done like this:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="es.cocode.baseapp.contact.ContactFragment">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="198dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="210dp">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_fullscreen_map"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fullscreen_white_48dp"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/map_fragment_container"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

It usually works like this:

[image: FAB working well]

But sometimes the bug appears and the anchor doesn't work:

[image: FAB not working]

Is there a way to solve this, or should I wait until this bug gets fixed and use 24.1.1 instead?

Comment: `CoordinatorLayout` inside the `ScrollView`? Try wrapping only the scrollable content (the FrameLayout) in the ScrollView.

Comment: All is "scrollable content" (after the FAB I have an include tag with the layout containing place, phone, mail and website).

Comment: Same thing is happening to me. Most of the times the fab's anchor gravity works fine, but sometimes it doesn't, resulting in what you described. oh well, reverting for now...

Comment: @JoaoSousa I have posted an answer.

Comment: In my case I don't even have a map, but I get that it probably happens due to measurement changes in the layouts. I don't really feel like attaching listeners and controlling the fab's visibility, but maybe I don't have a choice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to set the `FloatingActionButton` visibility to `GONE` in the XML and when the map is ready set it back to `VISIBLE`.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    . . .
    yourFAB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**EDIT:** This is a workaround for this [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221387&q=24.2.1&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened).

Comment: link provided helped me, #7 answer provided in that link worked for me

Answer (score 4):

As for 5/2/2017 (25.3.1) the bug still hasn't been fixed. After trying all solutions, the only one that worked for me was:

```
yourView.post(new Runnable() { 
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        yourView.requestLayout(); 
    } 
});
```

Where `yourView` is the anchored view.

Comment: Solution used in Xamarin.Android and fix the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Marked as Fixed
Issue is fixed and released in 26.0.0 version of support library.

Answer (score 1):

[Bug reported](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221387&q=24.2.1&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened) and hopefully fixed soon. Please star it.

Answer (score 0):

Well my friend there is another way to it using latest support libraries and not using any other thing .

Just use this -

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />
```

Comment: Can you explain this answer?

Comment: To be honest brother. I got this answer by dragging FAB in design section. It is working perfectly ever since even when I change the AppBar height .