# Floating Action Button doesn't appear correctly

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-tablayout, floating-action-button

I have a `floating action button` in my `Fragment` inside a `TabLayout`.

When the page loads, the button stays like this:

[image]

After I click on "Quilometragem final" field, the keyboard shows up and then my button stays in correct position:

[image]

How can I fix this to show my `floating action button` in correct position when page loads?

This is my layout's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/common_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/common_margin">

      <!-- another fields -->

      <!-- KM FINAL -->
      <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/end_exam_mileage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:textColor="@color/primary" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/txtFinalKM"
              android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
              android:inputType="number"
              android:hint="@string/end_exam_insert_mileage"
              android:textSize="25sp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
          <!-- NEXT BUTTON -->
        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_next_information"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/common_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/common_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_fab_mini_next"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:fab_shadowColor="#00FFFFFF"
            app:fab_colorNormal="#272B35"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@color/accent"
            app:fab_colorRipple="#272B35" />
  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43735231/7557205

Comment: @AswinPAshok thank you very much!

Comment: Glad you got it working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Aswin P Ashok comment, I was able to fix this *bug* reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39600012/bug-with-anchored-floatingactionbutton-in-support-library-24-2-1/43735231#43735231).

The solution was to add the following code inside `OnCreateView` in my `Fragment`:

```
_linearLayout.Post(new Runnable(() =>
{
    _linearLayout.RequestLayout();
}));
```

Why this works?

As told [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37118105),

> Posting requestLayout() works because the dependency graph is being built in the onMeasure() method
>   of CoordinatorLayout. After building the graph once, the
>   findAnchorView() method was called for every child. In the next pass
>   when building the graph in onMeasure() the method dependsOn() returns
>   correct result (unless some new views were added, for them it will not
>   work) and the graph builds correctly. It has to be called in post(),
>   because calling requestLayout() before the previous measure/layout
>   pass begins does not cause new pass.

Answer (score 2):

Change gravity to bottom|right

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_next_information"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/common_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/common_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_fab_mini_next"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:fab_shadowColor="#00FFFFFF"
            app:fab_colorNormal="#272B35"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@color/accent"
            app:fab_colorRipple="#272B35" />
```

Also in your parent layout you can add

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

to prevent cliping

Comment: What is cliping?

Comment: cliping is when something is above another thing , or in this case, your parent view is cliping your fab button, it means that one element overlaps the other

Comment: Nice! I'll try this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- another fields -->

            <!-- KM FINAL -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="end_exam_mileage"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txtFinalKM"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                        android:hint="end_exam_insert_mileage"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_next_information"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_message"
            app:fab_colorNormal="#272B35"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@color/accent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            app:fab_colorRipple="#272B35"
            app:fab_shadowColor="#00FFFFFF" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: FloatingActionButton doesn't need to be inside a CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: @perozzo yes no need to use CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Your code doesn't have CoordinatorLayout. Can you update it ?

Comment: @perozzo why you need to use `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: Oh sorry, I understand wrongly. I'll try your solution.

Comment: Same behavior as before :(

Comment: @perozzo share your whole layout with question

Comment: I think the problem is with the TabLayout as I already use floating action button in other layouts (no TabLayout) and it works perfectly.

Comment: @perozzo yes may be

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170690/discussion-between-perozzo-and-nilesh-rathod).